# Show that a number of the form $2^{n}+1$ can never be an integer raised to an odd power.

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Generally I tried analyzing cases such as:

If there is $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2^n+1=a^{m}$ where $m$ is odd, then $a$ can not be negative. But a couldn't figure out what to do next.

I also tried using the factorization: $a^{m}+1=(a+1)(a^{m-1}-a^{m-2}+\dots+1)$ that makes sense for $m$ odd. I applied it after summing $1$ to both sides of the equation.

I did get some contradictions after concluding that $a+1$ divides $2(2^{n-1}+1)$ but I couldn't analyze all cases.

Comment: We have $2^n+1=(2^n+1)^1$, which is an integer raised to an odd power. Presumably, an odd exponent greater than or equal to $3$ was meant.

Comment: $2^n=a^{m}-1=(a-1)(a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}+...+1)$. Both factors should be powers of 2. $a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}+...+1\equiv m \pmod 2$. Therefore $m$ is even.

Comment: [Catlan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), also known as Mihailescu's theorem, states that $8,9$ is the only occurrence of two consecutive numbers that are perfect powers of natural numbers.

Comment: If $a$ is even , then $a^m$ is even, if $a$ is odd, then $a^m$ is odd. The even case leads to contradiction immediately. 

If $a$ is odd, then $a^m\equiv a\pmod 8$  and since $n>2$ forces $a-1$ to be a multiple of $8$,  then $a\equiv 1\pmod 8$  in those cases of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

$a$ should odd because $2^n$ is even.

Then in the factorization $\underbrace{2^n}_\text{even}=\underbrace{(a-1)}_\text{even}\underbrace{(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{m-1}}_\text{m odd terms})$

And a sum of $m$ odd terms with $m$ odd cannot be even.

Comment: It's not enough for this argument that $2^n$ is _even_ -- the important part is that $2^n$ _has no odd factor_ other than $1$.

Comment: Yeah I redacted this a bit to quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $n\geq 3$.
We first note that $a$ cannot be even as then $1=2^n-a^m$ would be even.

We have
$$ 2^n=a^m - 1 = (a-1)(a^{m-1} + a^{m-2} +\dots +a+1).$$
Now as $a$ is odd, we have $a^j=1$ mod $2$ for $j\in \mathbb{N}$. In particular we can write $a-1=2^\ell s$ with $s$ odd. As $a^m-1=2^n$, we get $\ell<n$. Thus, we get
mod $2$
$$0\equiv  2^{n-\ell} =  s(a^{m-1} + a^{m-2} +\dots +a+1) \equiv m \equiv 1.$$
Which gives a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand the last part: $a-1$ is even so how can that number be equivalent to $1$ modulo $2$ ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Good catch. We have to write $a-1=2^\ell s$ with $s$ odd. Then you get $$2^{n-\ell} = s (a^{m-1}+\dots+1)$$ and then we can reduce mod $2$ (as $2^n+1=a^m$ we have $\ell<n$). Will fix it tomorrow, need to go to sleep, otherwise I will not look great at my defense :)